# Admob ads delayed?

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk, ads

I'm using Corona SDK Starter, and I want to show an ad when they lose the game. However, when they lose, it takes several seconds for the ad to show. I've searched and haven't found a way to preload ads, but is there any way to make it show instantly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interstitial ad (which fits well with your use case). You can ask for them early, such as the start of the game. And then on game complete, if you have an ad, then display it. This will be quick.